# Why does my import statement have a syntax error in Deno but works ok in Nodejs?

Tags: syntax, deno

I'm testing with two VSCode setups; one running Deno, the other running Nodejs using the Sucrase compiler to transform the code so that I can write native ES6 modules. I have a very simple test: a small Class and a module that imports it. Here is the Deno VSCode setup.

My VSCode explorer panel looks like this.

```
    PLANNER-CODEBASE
        .vscode
            launch.json
            setting.txt
        src
            plannerFiles 
                ClassArrayList.js 
                main.js 
            log.ts 
            .gitignore
            .prettierrc 
            config.ts
            deps.ts
            index.ts
            makefile
            readMe.txt
            tsconfig.json
```

I run the code using this launch.json entry.

```
    {
      "name": "Debug Program",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run", "-A", "--unstable", "--inspect-brk", "./index.ts"],
      "port": 9229,
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
```

This is index.ts

```
    import main from './src/plannerFiles/main.js'
    main()
```

This is main.js

```
    const main = () => {
      console.log('Starting your Planner App')
      
      import { ArrayList } from './ClassArrayList.js'
      let myArrayList = new ArrayList()
      
      let row0 = ['11/22/1968', '29', 'Revolution 9', 'Beatles', 'The Beatles [White Album]']
      let row1 = ['1960', '6', 'Fools Rush In', 'Frank Sinatra', "Nice 'N' Easy"]
      let row2 = ['11/11/1971', '1', 'One of These Days', 'Pink Floyd', 'Meddle']
      myArrayList.add(row0)
      myArrayList.add(row1)
      myArrayList.add(row2)
      myArrayList[5] = 'five'
      let xx = myArrayList.length
      let xxx = myArrayList.getUpperBound()
      let x = myArrayList.item(0)
      let y = myArrayList[1]
      let zzz = myArrayList[5]
      myArrayList.clear()
      myArrayList = ['LEVEL0INDENT', 50, 100, 75, 75, 100, 100, 100, 100] //first value is for initial space
      let z = myArrayList[1]
      
      debugger
      // static clear = (obj) => (obj.length = 0)
      // ArrayList.clear(myArrayList)
    }
    export default main
```

This is ClassArrayList.js

```
    class ArrayList extends Array {
      constructor() {
        super()
      }
      add = (obj) => {
        this.push(obj)
      }
      item = (key) => {
        let obj = this.valueOf()[key]
        return obj
      }
      getUpperBound = () => {
        return this.valueOf().length - 1
      }
      clear = () => {
        this.valueOf().length = 0
      }
    }
    export { ArrayList }
```

This is my terminal output.

```
    ramData\chocolatey\bin\deno.exe run -A --unstable --inspect-brk ./index.ts
    Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/ws/fd15dc8c-111d-45e4-b09e-651aae5b01c7
    error: Expected LParen, got Some(LBrace) at file:///C:/Users/Bruce/Dropbox/Code/DENO%20BACKEND/Planner-Codebase/src/plannerFiles/main.js:4:9
```

I don't know what's wrong or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The provided code works, what's above the import, you need to show us code where we can reproduce the error.

Comment: I added the few additional code lines of the testing moduleMain.js to show the whole file. The environment is a VSCode project created from this repo: https://dev.to/lampewebdev/deno-the-node-replacement-bonus-i-created-a-boilerplate-for-deno-2g25. The only code in it is the two files shown in this question, as it was created to start testing a lot of code, and this class is the first to be tested. Index.js calls main.js which calls ArrayList. That's all there is.

Comment: P.S. This is deno 1.1.2

Comment: Works fine for me. As a sanity test, copy and paste the contents of the files in your post into files with the exact same names on your filesystem. Then [debug](https://deno.land/manual/tools/debugger) again.

Comment: The code works fine @MartinDuo post the complete code and what commands are you using to run it. The error says line 697, while the code posted here has ~28. Post full code so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: I have changed the post to show everything as copied from my project. I will try to provide whatever you request so we can solve this. Thanks for your responses so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of importing module inside function move outside like this. If you want to load module lazyly use [dynamic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports) import

**Try this:**

```
     import { ArrayList } from './ClassArrayList.js'
     const main = () => {
      console.log('Starting your Planner App');
      let myArrayList = new ArrayList();    
      let row0 = ['11/22/1968', '29', 'Revolution 9', 'Beatles', 'The Beatles [White Album]']
      let row1 = ['1960', '6', 'Fools Rush In', 'Frank Sinatra', "Nice 'N' Easy"]
      let row2 = ['11/11/1971', '1', 'One of These Days', 'Pink Floyd', 'Meddle']
      myArrayList.add(row0)
      myArrayList.add(row1)
      myArrayList.add(row2)
      myArrayList[5] = 'five'
      let xx = myArrayList.length
      let xxx = myArrayList.getUpperBound()
      let x = myArrayList.item(0)
      let y = myArrayList[1]
      let zzz = myArrayList[5]
      myArrayList.clear()
      myArrayList = ['LEVEL0INDENT', 50, 100, 75, 75, 100, 100, 100, 100] //first value is for initial space
      let z = myArrayList[1]
      
      debugger
      // static clear = (obj) => (obj.length = 0)
      // ArrayList.clear(myArrayList)
    }
    export default main
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it works. But as a newbie to writing JS outside of React, I assumed, for some reason, that imports were placed inside the function needing them. Too bad the error didn't say "SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module". Does putting it outside define ArrayList in global scope, or is it only within the file's scope? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you want to use inside function you have to use lazyLoading syntex. I am not sure but  using outside is filescope.